# Setting date format output in spring rest with gson

Tags: gson, spring-rest

I have a legacy application which uses Spring-Rest and Google-GSON (declared in pom.xml) for serializing/deserializing Objects. In one of these objects there's a java.util.Date property, I want to set the date format but I cannot find how to do it.

I can't even switch to Jackson because a colleague of mine uses it explicitly in a part of his code.

How can I set the date format in this scenario?

This application doesn't use Spring Boot. Everything I found for this problem is about Spring-boot + Jackson.

EDIT: I add some details. I have this Class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="WEB_ELENCO_SCHEMI")
@IdClass(PK.class)
public class WebElencoSchemi implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name="COD_ARCHIVIO_ARCAM")
    private BigDecimal codArchivioArcam;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name="DATA_AGGIORNAM")
    private Date dataAggiornam;

    ...
}
```

And this repository:

```
public interface WebElencoSchemiRepository extends CrudRepository<WebElencoSchemi, BigDecimal> {
    public List<WebElencoSchemi> findByCodArchivioArcam(BigDecimal codArchivioArcam);
```

I want to set the format of dataAggiornam JSON output. I'm using GSON as serializator/deserializator for Spring Rest, as defined in pom.xml.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

I tried adding a spring.gson.date-format property in my properties file with no success.

I'm NOT using Spring boot and I cannot switch to Jackson (in which the problem is solved with a simple annotation on the class property).

Comment: Can you give an example of what you are looking for? That will be more helpful.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I edited the question with code examples, hope this can give a better view of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a date format while creating the Gson object with the GsonBuilder.

Something like;

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm").serializeNulls().create();
```

It has a bunch of other factory methods which are super useful also, for your perusal. Love this library.